# Which is the equivalent function in matlab for bytearray() in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having troubles trying to convert a python code to matlab.
I have this code, it takes values from the ui and makes a stpack from struct library which packs the values in the way indicated `"<fififfIi"`. The code is shown below.

```
config_data = bytearray(stpack("<fififfIi", self.sample_freq.get(), int(self.run_time.get()*self.sample_freq.get()), self.bia_freq.get(), self.mode.get(), self.sweep_start.get(), self.sweep_stop.get(), int(np.ceil(self.sweep_points.get())), self.sweep_type.get()))
```

The result I get, which is correct, is `bytearray(b'050000.00 01006.441895 0000.789513\x00')`

I tried to reproduce that in matlab and I was told to use the following code:

```
config_data = uint8([char("<fififfIi"), 1, 10, 50000, 0, 500, 50000, 10, 0]);
```

The numbers inside the function are similar to the real ones but it is just to test the output of the code. However when I take a look at the output, this is what I get:

```
>> NanoBlA4Wire
Columns 1 through 7

    60   102   105   102   105   102   102

  Columns 8 through 14

    73   105     1    10   255     0   255

  Columns 15 through 17

   255    10     0
```

I don't understand what the output is or how can I obtain the same output as python in matlab. Does anybody have any idea on what am I missing?

Comment: Well, the first 9 bytes of that output are the characters "<fififfIi", so it's not really doing the packing you think it is.

Comment: I don't think Matlab has any functions to pack and unpack heterogeneous data like that.  I couldn't even find any good add-on packages.  Can you store that data in another way?

Comment: Where did you find `stpack`?  That's certainly not the results you'd get from `struct.pack`.

Comment: I forgot to put it in the question, stpack is the same as function pack from struct module, it's just renamed in the code.

Comment: That's impossible.  `struct.pack` on that data would not produce human-readable output like you show above.

Comment: Example: from this `config_data = bytearray(struct.pack("<fififfIi", 123.456, 12345, 2345.67, 99, 123.45, 234.56, 11335577, 145 ) )` we get this:
`bytearray(b'y\xe9\xf6B90\x00\x00\xb8\x9a\x12Ec\x00\x00\x00f\xe6\xf6B\\\x8fjC\x99\xf7\xac\x00\x91\x00\x00\x00')`.  That's typical
>>>

Comment: Where will this "byte array" go? The most straightforward generalized serialization method in MATLAB that I can think of is "save".